# Graphical representation of connection of people

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I want to make a graphical representation of the people with the location, but coding is a little bit challenging.

Here is my input {Person,Location,Influences}

```
list = {{"John", 
"Michigan", {"Kelly", "Ralph", "James", "Kim", "Brown"}}, 
{"Kelly", "Minnesota", {"James", "Tim"}}, {"Kale", 
"Texas", {"Paul", "Claro"}}, {"Claro", "Texas", {}}, {"Ralph", 
"France", {"William", "Daniel"}}, {"Edwin", 
"France", {"William", "Kale"}}};
```

and I want my output to be graphical image such as

[image]

What is a good way to start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`CommunityGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommunityGraphPlot.html) after constructing an edge list and community structure based on `list`:

```
edges = Flatten[Thread[First[#] -> Last[#]] & /@ list]
groups = GroupBy[list, #[[2]] &, Flatten[#[[All, {1, -1}]]] &]

CommunityGraphPlot[Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
 Values @ groups, 
 CommunityLabels -> Keys[groups],
 CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.5, #]& /@ RandomColor[Length@Keys@groups]), 
 ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]

An alternative definition of `groups` produces something closer to your picture:

```
groups = GroupBy[list, #[[2]] &, #[[All, 1]] &];
CommunityGraphPlot[Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
   Values @ groups, 
   CommunityLabels -> Keys[groups],
   CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.5, #] & /@ RandomColor[Length @ Keys @ groups]), 
   ImageSize -> Large] /. BezierCurve -> ( Line[#[[{1, -1}]]] &)
```

[image]

Since this is a `Graphics` object you can double-click on it and make changes;, e.g., you can move the node `"William"` outside the `"France"` blob to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know why it does not work in my MMA. hmm.

Comment: @SaesunKim  what version/os are you using? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I copied your code (nice solution) and CommunityGraphPlot isn't working for me with this code.  The intermediate values seem fine.  Am I doing something wrong?  And I'm not getting an error message, but rather, CommunityGraphPlot isn't evaluating.  I'm using V12.0.0 on a mac.  If I just use CommunityGraphPlot[Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]] it seems fine.

Comment: @kglr I am using version 11.0. I do not get any error message, and I can plot the CommunityGraphPlot. But when I the code, communicityGroupplot isn't working

Comment: I stripped out what didn't work and found that the problem I'm seeing seems to be with the communities.  CommunityLabels and CommunityRegionStyle are fine if I add them.  The graph that I say is "fine" only has 3 regions (communities) - it is missing France.

Comment: Got it - you fixed a typo in the original that had "Claro" and "Calro".  I did that and get your graph!  It is this line in the original data: {"Kale", "Texas", {"Paul", "Calro"}}

Comment: Yeah Thank you!

Comment: I did see that "Paul" is not a primary in your list, meaning no place is assigned for Paul.  list[[;;,1]] gives  {"John", "Kelly", "Kale", "Claro", "Ralph", "Edwin"}.  That is why Paul is assigned to the "Texas" community.